# How can we access memory outside of a Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, node.js, n-api

For example, suppose there is some other program outside of Node.js, that wants to coordinate with a Node.js application to give it direct access to some memory.

On the JavaScript side, I suppose we'll need an ArrayBuffer.

Do we need to write a Node.js C++ addon module to to do this? (I'm imagining to use C++ if so, but if we can use other languages like Rust that'd be cool.)

Any guidance on where to look for getting started on something like this?

Comment: An option is to use IPC over sockets

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out apache arrow?
https://arrow.apache.org/

It supports a lot of languages and allows access to defined external memory, for sharing data between applications of different Languages.